# What special features does Compass have?

Tags: css, haml, sass, blueprint-css, compass-sass

What features does Compass have that the standard Sass portion of the HAML gem does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass

A Sass-based CSS Meta-Framework that allows you to mix and match any of the following CSS frameworks:

- Compass Core, Blueprint, 960, Susy, YUI
- Other frameworks can be added relatively easily